# Title/Author List Clashing with Page Numbers

Tags: titles, page-numbering, author

On even-numbered pages, Latex prints the page number on the top left and the list of authors centered. On odd-numbered pages (except page 1), it prints the page number on the top right and the title centered. The problem is: When either the author list or the title is too long, it crashes into the page number.

Here's my setup.

```
\begin{document}
\title{If the title is too long, it clashes with page numbers}
\author{If the author list is too long, it clashes with page numbers}
\maketitle
```

How can I prevent this clash? Thanks

Edit: Sorry for the slow response. The document class is 11pt amsart.
And here are the use statements near the start of my document:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
```

I'm not sure the packages are relevant here though. At least, the problem can trigger without including any packages at all. Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
\title{This title is too long it will clash with odd-numbered page numbers}
\author{This author list is too long it will clash with even-numbered page numbers}
\maketitle

Blah
\newpage
Blah
\newpage
Blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't give any information about which documentclass or packages you use, which is important as this determines how the page headers are setup. However, most documentclasses support either optional arguments for the author and title fields to be displayed in the header (while the original title and authors are displayed at the start of the document), such as `\title[short title here]{longer title here}`, or something like a separate `\shorttitle{}` command, or `\runningauthors` or something similar. You can check the documentation of your documentclass for the exact syntax.

Comment: For now I'll vote to close as "needs details", you can avoid closing if you provide a complete document including the documentclass, any packages that might influence the titles, some content (use for example the `lipsum` package to fill a few pages with a single command for demonstration purposes), and a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` statement. This should allow us to reproduce the issue without adding any code ourselves. If the question gets closed (with 5 community votes) before you add the minimal document then you can still add it and it will be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsart` class allows for short forms of the title and author list as optional argument.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
\title[This title is shorter]{This title is too long it will clash with odd-numbered page numbers}
\author[John Smith et al.]{This author list is too long it will clash with even-numbered page numbers}
\maketitle

Blah
\newpage
Blah
\newpage
Blah

\end{document}
```

From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf), page 11:

> Unless the title is very short, provide a form of the title suitable for use in
> running heads. This should be entered in brackets between the tag `\title` and
> the full title: `\title[short title]{full title}`. The length can best be judged by
> checking the output when using AMS style files. Do not use author-defined macros
> in the title.

Page 12:

> If the author name(s) cannot fit in the space available for the running head,
> enter a shortened form for each name in [brackets] between the tag `\author` and
> the full name. Acceptable shortened forms use initials for all but the surname(s).
> For example,
>
> `\author[J. Smith]{Joseph Smith}`
>
> If the list of shortened author names is still too long for the running head (including
> a reasonable space for the page number), it can be shortened for an article as in
> the following example:
> `\author[J. Smith et al.]{Joseph Smith}`
>
> `...`
>
> `\author[]{second name}`
>
> `...`
>
> `\author[]{final name}`

Note that according to the manual you should give each author their own `\author` command, and not provide the full list in a single command as you seem to do in the MWE.